# HTTPServer with greater degree of control in Python

Tags: python, python-multithreading, httpserver

I have a fairly simple problem that I would like to solve in Python.

I would like a webserver that has the following behavior: if it receives a POST request for `/work`, then it should add it to a work queue and execute some function on the data attached. If it receives a POST request for `/cancel` it should cancel whatever its current task is.

Unfortunately, the only way I can seem to get a `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` to handle multiple requests is to use a `ThreadingMixIn`, but that seems unecessarily complicated as I then have to use a set of locks to prevent multiple work tasks from executing concurrently.

I tried to use a `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` without a `ThreadingMixIn` and just spin off threads in `do_POST`, but that didn't work since apparently `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` closes its connection when the `do_POST` function returns.

Ideally, I'm looking for an interface that gives me the ability to close the connection to the client on my own terms, so I can do it in a worker thread, and manage the queue myself, rather than working around the `ThreadingMixIn`'s behavior in this regard.